# Can I create a directive without a module?

Tags: angularjs-directive

I typically have been defining my controllers as such:

```
<body data-ng-app>
  <div data-ng-controller='IndexCtrl'>
  </div>
</body>
```

so my controller is defined:

```
var indexController = function($scope) { /* ... */ }
```

can I do the same with directives? it seems I have to go an name the ng-app to create a directive?

Answer (score 0):

1. "Can I create a directive without a module?"

No.  I'm pretty sure Angular requires directives be in modules.  And then you need to have the module loaded to consume the directive.  So if you do `angular.module('myApp', [])` as your main module and you want to use a library `'myLib'` then you /have/ to make the main module depend on `myLib` somehow (i.e. `angular.module('myApp', ['myLib'])`.

1. "it seems I have to go an name the ng-app to create a directive"

Not exactly. If you use an already-existing-in-vanilla-angular module, you could (although I don't know why you want to do this in the first place) do this:

**Javascript**

```
angular.module('ng').directive('sample', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: '<b> YAYYYYYY </b>'
  }
});
```

**Template**

```
<sample></sample>
```